# Need to fetch not null values oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

Table structure looks like this

Table T1

| Col1 | COl2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | A | null |
| B | null | null |
| null | null | C |
| D | null | E |

Want to fetch `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E` (Not null values)

Comment: This is an unusual request. So, D and E are related somehow, while A, B, and C are not. But you still want a mere list of them all. What if a value appears twice in the table? Do you want it twice in your results or just once?

Comment: SQL works with data sets, not values. SQL result set is not a spreadsheet, it has tabular structure: rows and columns. Please, describe what you want to achieve using this semantics, show your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT value
FROM   t1
UNPIVOT (value FOR key IN (col1, col2, col3))
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (Col1, COl2, Col3) AS
SELECT NULL, 'A', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', NULL, 'E'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | A |
> | B |
> | C |
> | D |
> | E |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b36273de2c4033797a922de38836518c)*